# Pagination in Jekyll + Skinnybones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I only want to show six posts at a time on the homepage, how can I paginate this?

I use the following display code;

```
<div class="row">
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% include post-grid.html %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

and this is the post...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h2><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
</div>
```

I want to show 6 at a time and then some basic bootstrap style pagination.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions on how to configure `jekyll-paginate`:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

There you'll find all steps you need to enable pagination and render the paginated posts, and all page-related attributes available.